# Does anyone know a good design to manage a group of multi-read single-write resources in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

**Problem:** As the title, say, I have a group of resources I need to manage in a multi-threaded C++ program. Each resource should allow multi-read single-write access. Does anyone know a good design to solve this problem?

**Attempted solution:** The following outlines what I'm thinking about:

Given a resource as:

```
struct Resource {
    //...
};
```

I have a global Token Manager used to manage read/write tokens:

```
class TokenManager {
    private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_mutex> m_tokens;

    auto &fetch(const int key) {
        std::lock_guard g(m_mutex);
        return m_tokens[key];
    }

    public:
    auto CreateWriteToken(const int key) {
        return WriteToken{key, fetch(key)};
    }

    auto CreateReadToken(const int key) {
        return ReadToken{key, fetch(key)};
    }
};
```

The WriteToken represent write access to the resource, and it is derived from the Token base class:

```
class Token {
    Resource m_resource;
    
    protected:
    Token(const int key) {
        //open resource based on key
    };

    public:
    void Visit(const Visitor v) {
        v(m_resouce);
    }
};

class WriteToken : public Token {
    std::unique_lock m_lock;

    public:
    WriteToken(const int key, std::shared_mutex &m) : Token(key), m_lock(m) {}
};
```

The ReadToken represent read access to the resource:

```
class ReadToken : public Token {
    std::shared_lock m_lock;

    public:
    ReadToken(const int key, std::shared_mutex &m) : Token(key), m_lock(m) {}
};
```

Can you see any obvious flaw in this design? Do you know a better design?

Comment: Sounds like you want a read-write lock e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks
You will have to decide if you also need it to support reentrancy, fairness, promotion/demotion, ...

Comment: It depends on how callers use them. The design doesn't show how does it manage m_resource. Also it seems impossible for sharing a resource of between `WriteToken` and `ReadToken` since themselves are derived from `Token`.

Comment: Usually you'd store the resource in the map too and provide the token a pointer to that resource. Of course the `Visit` function should be made part of the concrete token classes in order to allow you to cast the reference to `const` for `ReadToken`. Furthermore almost certainly passing `Visitor` by value is a design flaw: You'll have a hard time applying different logic. `template<class F> void Visit(F&&f){std::forward<F>(f)(m_resource); }` would be much more flexible...

Comment: Arguably you could improve locking by guarding access to the map with a shared mutex too and use `find` + a shared lock for creating a read token. (This is assuming creating a non-existing resource for reading would be considered a write operation)